# How can I fix my Android SQLite Database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database

I'm a beginner programmer making an android app, so I really need your help.
I know that my question is super long, but I will be grateful if you guys answer my quest

I am making an app that selects 1 word randomly from many words in a table.

Thus, I made my Database with SQLite. I tried these things.

1. I made WordDBHelper to use SQLiteOpenHelper
2. I made WordDBRecord to put records in a table
3. I made WordActivty to open DB and to see a word selected from a table through TextView.setText().

These are my codes

1. Word Activity

```java
public class WordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WordDBRecord wordDBRecord;
    String category = wordDBRecord.category;
    String word = wordDBRecord.word;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWord);

        wordDBRecord = new WordDBRecord(this);
        wordDBRecord.open();
        wordDBRecord.DBSearch("KeyWordDB");
        t1.setText(category);
        t2.setText(word);
        wordDBRecord.close();
        }
    }
```

2. WordDBHelper(using SQLite Open Helper)

```java
    import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

    public class WordDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
         static final String TABLE_NAME = "KeyWordDB";

    public WordDBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        Log.d(TAG, "DataBaseHelper");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Table Create");

        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +
                "( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "CATEGORY TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                "WORD TEXT NOT NULL);";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Table onUpgrade");
        String createQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + ";";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createQuery);
        }
    }
```

3.WordDBRecord( Class putting Records)

```java
    import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

    public class WordDBRecord {
    public String id;
    public String category;
    public String word;
    private Context context;
    private WordDBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public WordDBRecord(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public WordDBRecord open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new WordDBHelper(context, "DB", null, 1);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

          dbInsert("KeyWordDB", "Movie", "Harry Potter");

        return this;
    }

    public void DBSearch(String tableName) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = database.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                    category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CATEGORY"));
                    word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("WORD"));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        database.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void dbInsert(String tableName, String category, String word) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Insert Data ");

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("CATEGORY", category);
        contentValues.put("WORD", word);

        long id = database.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
        Log.d(TAG, "id: " + id);
    }

    }
```

So I ran my app but I failed to open an app. My app stopped when I clicked my app.
I received those Logcats

```
    2019-12-15 11:37:59.005 22791-22791/org.techtown.worddbpractice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.techtown.worddbpractice, PID: 22791
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.techtown.worddbpractice/org.techtown.worddbpractice.WordActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String org.techtown.worddbpractice.WordDBRecord.category' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2849)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String org.techtown.worddbpractice.WordDBRecord.category' on a null object reference
        at org.techtown.worddbpractice.WordActivity.<init>(WordActivity.java:17)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2839)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

I really want to fix these problems, but I don't know how...
I will be really really grateful, if someone answers my super long question.
Thank you

Comment: This may help understand the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: The error appears at "String category = wordDBRecord.category;". Because 'wordDBRecord' object is still not created in earlier line. You may declare category and word as empty string.

Comment: Read the error message carefully - it is all about something not initialized. The comment above tells already this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation

The issue you are facing is that when you use **`private WordDBRecord wordDBRecord;`** this declares the variable **wordDBRecord** as being of type WordDBRecord, which is not a [primative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) type but an ***Object***.

**Declaring** a variable that is not a primative type results in that variable being **null** (i.e no instance of the object exists (the object has not been created)).

- In link above in the section entitle **Default Values**, it includes :-
  [image]

So when the next line **`String category = wordDBRecord.category;`** is encountered there is **no object wordDBRecord** instead the **pointer to the object is set to null** to indicate this. So when the asttempt is made to get the category from the object you get the **null pointer exception** (you cannot get something from nothing).

*If the next line `String word = wordDBRecord.word;` were to be encountered the same issue would result.*

## How to Fix (the null pointer exception)

The fix is simple, **do not try to set that values for category and word by trying to use wordDBRecord until wordDBRecord has been instantiated**. The instantiation is done by the line `wordDBRecord = new WordDBRecord(this);`.

As such you want to only declare the **category** and the **word** variables. e.g.

```
public class WordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WordDBRecord wordDBRecord; //<<<<< only declares wordDBrecord so it is null
    String category; //<<<<< CHANGED TO ONLY DECLARE category
    String word; //<<<<< CHANGED TO ONLY DECALRE word

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWord);

        wordDBRecord = new WordDBRecord(this); //<<<<< instantiates wordDBRecord so it is now not null
        wordDBRecord.open();
        wordDBRecord.DBSearch("KeyWordDB");
        t1.setText(category);
        t2.setText(word);
        wordDBRecord.close();
    }
}
```

## HOWEVER - Complete FIX

After applying the fix you will **not** see Movie and Harry Potter in the TextViews.

This is because when the above runs it declares category and word but they are never set (*they are null but the setText method checks for this and bypasses the null pointer exception*). You would need to set the values e.g. after the line `wordDBRecord.DBSearch("KeyWordDB");` use :-

```
        category = wordRecordDB.category;
        word = wordRecordDB.word;
        t1.setText(category);
        t2.setText(word);
```

As you can get the values directly from the wordDBRecord object. Having variable category and word is not even required. As such you could use the more compact :-

```
public class WordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WordDBRecord wordDBRecord; //<<<<< only declares wordDBrecord so it is null

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWord);

        wordDBRecord = new WordDBRecord(this); //<<<<< instantiates wordDBRecord so it is now not null
        wordDBRecord.open();
        wordDBRecord.DBSearch("KeyWordDB");
        t1.setText(wordDBRecord.category);
        t2.setText(wordDBRecord.word);
        wordDBRecord.close();
    }
}
```

Using the above rsults in :-

[image]

With the log containing :-

```
2019-12-16 10:14:37.773 D/Constraints: DataBaseHelper
2019-12-16 10:14:37.789 D/Constraints: Table Create
2019-12-16 10:14:37.794 D/Constraints: Insert Data 
2019-12-16 10:14:37.798 D/Constraints: id: 1
```

## Additional

On a similar subject matter the SQliteDatabase query method will never return a Cursor that is null. Setting the Cursor to null before retrieving it and checking for null after retrieving it is not required.

As such your **DBSearch** method could be :-

```
public void DBSearch(String tableName) {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(tableName,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
        category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CATEGORY"));
        word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("WORD"));
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this query in DBSearch() method.

```
public void DBSearch(String tableName) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM "+tablename, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CATEGORY"));
                word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("WORD"));
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```